# Date Picker Jquery exibir em formato d/m/Y e gravar no banco formato Y-m-d

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, datepicker

Estou usando este datepicker em meu projeto, já esta configurado como podem ver abaixo o DateFormat no formato d/m/Y, mais gostaria que quando eu fosse salvar no banco ele converteria para o formato Y-m-d, como poderia fazer isso?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="calendario" id="calendario"/>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
</script>

<?php 
$anos = isset($_POST['calendario']) ? $_POST['calendario'] : '';
echo $anos;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar isso:
`$dataEnviadoPorPost = str_replace("/", "-", $_POST["calendario"]);`
`echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataEnviadaPorPost));`